# tensorflow conv3d ignoring 1st spacial dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Im using tensorflow 1.0.0 on OSX, but the same problem occured with version 1.0.1.

you can run this script to produce the error

## **Relevant code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def conv3d(inputs,weights, biases,layer_name,act=tf.nn.relu,padding='VALID'):
    preactivate = tf.nn.conv3d(inputs,weights,strides=[1,1,1,1,1],padding=padding) + biases
    activation = act(preactivate) 
    return activation        

def maxpool(inputs,padding='VALID'):
    return tf.nn.max_pool3d(inputs,ksize=[1,2,2,2,1],strides=[1,2,2,2,1],padding=padding)

def weight_variable(shape,dtype=np.float32,partition_info=None):
    shape[shape==None] = 1
    n = np.prod(shape)
    w = (np.random.randn(n) * np.sqrt(2./n)).astype(np.float32)
    return tf.Variable(w.reshape(shape),trainable=True)

## initializes biases
def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial,trainable=True)

def mean_square_error(a,b):
    shape = a.get_shape().as_list()
    shape[shape==None] = 1
    N = np.prod(shape)
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.squared_difference(a,b)) / N


###  low level api ################################ 
def ll_model(inputs):

    input_layer = tf.reshape(inputs,[-1,65,65,65,2])

    W_conv1 = weight_variable([3,3,3,2,16])
    b_conv1 = bias_variable([16])
    conv1 = conv3d(input_layer,W_conv1,b_conv1,'conv1')

    print(conv1.get_shape().as_list())

    pad = tf.pad(conv1,[[0,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[0,0]],mode='CONSTANT')
    print(pad.get_shape().as_list())

    maxpool1 = maxpool(pad)
    print(maxpool1.get_shape().as_list())

    W_conv2 = weight_variable([3,3,3,16,24])
    b_conv2 = bias_variable([24])
    conv2 = conv3d(maxpool1,W_conv2, b_conv2,'conv2',padding="SAME")
    print(conv2.get_shape().as_list())

    W_conv3 = weight_variable([3,3,3,24,28])
    b_conv3 = bias_variable([28])
    conv3 = conv3d(conv2,W_conv3,b_conv3,'conv3',padding="SAME")
    print(conv3.get_shape().as_list())

    W_conv4 = weight_variable([4,4,4,28,34])
    b_conv4 = bias_variable([34])
    conv4 = conv3d(conv3,W_conv4,b_conv4,'conv4')
    print(conv4.get_shape().as_list())

    W_conv5 = weight_variable([5,5,5,34,42])
    b_conv5 = bias_variable([42])
    conv5 = conv3d(conv4,W_conv5,b_conv5,'conv5')
    print(conv5.get_shape().as_list())

    W_conv6 = weight_variable([5,5,5,42,50])
    b_conv6 = bias_variable([50])
    conv6 = conv3d(conv5,W_conv6,b_conv6,'conv6')
    print(conv6.get_shape().as_list())

    W_conv7 = weight_variable([5,5,5,50,50])
    b_conv7 = bias_variable([50])
    conv7 = conv3d(conv6,W_conv7,b_conv7,'conv7')
    print(conv7.get_shape().as_list())

    W_conv8 = weight_variable([1,1,1,50,2])
    b_conv8 = bias_variable([2])
    conv8 = conv3d(conv7,W_conv8, b_conv8,'output')

    return conv8


sess = tf.Session()    
## placeholders
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,65,65,65,2],name='features')


y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,17,17,17,2],name='targets')

loss = mean_square_error(y,ll_model(x))
```

the error happens when compiling the model. conv8 is supposed to have the shape [None,17,17,17,2].

## The Error:

```
python task.py                                                                       
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 ins
tructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.                     
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 ins
tructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.                     
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instru
ctions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.                        
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instr
uctions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.                       
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instru
ctions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.                        
[None, 65, 63, 63, 16]                                                                                      
[None, 66, 64, 64, 16]                                                                                      
[None, 33, 32, 32, 16]                                                                                      
[None, 33, 32, 32, 24]                                                                                      
[None, 33, 32, 32, 28]                                                                                      
[None, 33, 29, 29, 34]                                                                                      
[None, 33, 25, 25, 42]                                                                                      
[None, 33, 21, 21, 50]                                                                                      
[None, 33, 17, 17, 50]                                                                                      
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                          
  File "/Users/vhasfclanga/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/
common_shapes.py", line 670, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl                                                     
    status)                                                                                                 
  File "/Users/vhasfclanga/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__      
    next(self.gen)                                                                                          
  File "/Users/vhasfclanga/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/
errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status                                              
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))                                                                   
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 17 and 33 fo
r 'SquaredDifference' (op: 'SquaredDifference') with input shapes: [?,17,17,17,2], [?,33,17,17,2].          

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                         

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                          
  File "task.py", line 33, in <module>                                                                      
    loss = mean_square_error(y,ll_model(x))                                                                 
  File "/Users/vhasfclanga/tflow_trainer/trainer/functions.py", line 80, in mean_square_error               
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.squared_difference(a,b)) / N                                                    
  File "/Users/vhasfclanga/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_ma
th_ops.py", line 2754, in squared_difference                                                                
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("SquaredDifference", x=x, y=y, name=name)                                 
  File "/Users/vhasfclanga/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/
op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op                                                                   
    op_def=op_def)                                                                                          
  File "/Users/vhasfclanga/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/
ops.py", line 2397, in create_op                                                                            
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)                                                                             
  File "/Users/vhasfclanga/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/
ops.py", line 1757, in set_shapes_for_outputs                                                               
    shapes = shape_func(op)                                                                                 
  File "/Users/vhasfclanga/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/
ops.py", line 1707, in call_with_requiring                                                                  
    return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)                                                     
  File "/Users/vhasfclanga/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/
common_shapes.py", line 610, in call_cpp_shape_fn                                                           
    debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)                                                                
  File "/Users/vhasfclanga/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/
common_shapes.py", line 675, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl                                                     
    raise ValueError(err.message)                                                                           
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 17 and 33 for 'SquaredDifference' (op: 'SquaredDifference') wi
th input shapes: [?,17,17,17,2], [?,33,17,17,2].
```

As you can see, these are the shapes of the tensors resulting from each convolutional layer.

[None, 65, 63, 63, 16]
[None, 66, 64, 64, 16]
[None, 33, 32, 32, 16]
[None, 33, 32, 32, 24]
[None, 33, 32, 32, 28]
[None, 33, 29, 29, 34]
[None, 33, 25, 25, 42]
[None, 33, 21, 21, 50]
[None, 33, 17, 17, 50]

Notice the first spacial dimension is only effected by pooling and padding layers, and is totally ignored by convolutional layers. It's strange to me because everything should be symmetric across spatial dimensions.

I've tried using tf.nn.convolution , that yielded the same result. I've tried switching up the padding, that also didn't work. I tried using the higher level functions in tf.layers to construct the model, that also didn't work. The fact that none of these methods worked makes me think this must be a programming error on my part, but the error is coming from a simple propagation of tensor shapes, starting with placeholders

```
with tf.name_scope('inputs'):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,65,65,65,2],name='features')
    tf.summary.histogram('feature-hist', x)
with tf.name_scope('ground_truth'):
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,17,17,17,2],name='targets')
    tf.summary.histogram('target-hist', y)
```

So I'm not sure where I could have possibly gone wrong.

Also, this exact model structure resulted in the correct output shape when used with the Estimator + ModelFnOps API.

Does anyone know if this is a bug or programming error on my part?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: I looked over the tf docs, your model, and conv3d implementation and I don't see what's wrong. I'd be interested to see what the resolution to this problem is.

Comment: I posted the same question on github -> https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8596

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I return to answer my question with my head bowed. I played myself.

The problem is this line

`shape[shape==None] = 1`

in `weight_variable`.

Since shape in this case is just a normal python list, `shape==None` is not evaluated element-wise and just evaluates to `False`, and then for some reason `shape[False]` returns `shape[0]`. which is why the first dimension of all the kernels are 1.

Modifying the `weight_variable` function to this

```
def weight_variable(shape,dtype=np.float32,partition_info=None):
    n = np.prod(shape)
    w = (np.random.randn(n) * np.sqrt(2./n)).astype(np.float32)
    return tf.Variable(w.reshape(shape),trainable=True)
```

works fine.